# Array to string conversion error in the headers

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I am facing this issue when I try to connect to the webhook with a token sent from the frontend.

Here is the function to handle the creation of a webhook

```php
try {
    $response = Http::withHeaders(["X-MANAGER-TOKEN" => $clientInformation["meta"]["accessToken"]])
        ->withToken(config("hello.ACCESS_TOKEN"))
        ->post(
            config("hello.BASE_URL") . "/managers/webhooks",
            [
                "event" => 'order.status.update',
                "target_url" => config("app.url") . "/api/hello/validate",
                "original_id" => random_int(0, 9999999999),
                "subscriber" => 'BBC',
                "conditions" => [
                    "status" => 'new',
                ],
            ]
        );

    if ($response->successful()) {
        $clientInformation["meta"]["webhooks"]["order"] = $response->body();

        return $clientInformation;
    }
    
    return $clientInformation;
} catch (Exception) {
    return $clientInformation;
}
```

From the frontend, I sent the access token in Vuejs with other data in this way:

```
this.clientForm.is_third_party = true;
this.clientForm.meta = { accessToken: this.meta };
```

Here is the error from the backend:

> error: {message: "Array to string conversion", line: 524,…} file: "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Str.php"
> line: 524 message: "Array to string conversion" stack: [{file:
> "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framew

Comment: Looks like `Http::withHeaders` accepts an array of key/value pairs, you are passing a multi dimensional array

Comment: I think it accepts

Comment: Can you share the full error ? It should throw which method is giving you this error. Is it `withHeaders`, or `withToken` or maybe other ?